# Pandas - How to create series of x - y, x - y*2, x - y*3, etc in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series, analysis

I have a dataframe that shows the quarterly forecasted amount of an item in one column, and using amount / 13 I can come up with the forecasted weekly consumption. (With there being 13 weeks in a quarter).
My question is this: I also have the current quantity on hand of each item in a separate column. I'd like to add an additional column that represents each week in the quarter, and shows the inventory quantity on hand decreasing by the forecasted weekly amount.
I understand what the formula would be if I were to manually add these columns, but I can't help but imagine there is a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Current data would look something like this:

```
    item_number    |   qty   | quarter | onhand  |       weekly
-------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------------------
 M17-4R1.0         |   20.79 |       2 |   32.00 |    1.59884615384615
 M17-4R1.25        |   22.24 |       2 |  -42.02 |    1.71075384615385
 M17-4R1.375       |   36.12 |       2 |   77.72 |              2.7782
 M17-4R1.5         |   74.29 |       2 |  134.12 |    5.71446923076924
 M17-4R1.625       |   46.35 |       2 |   63.10 |    3.56513076923077
 M17-4R.369        |   86.79 |       2 |   16.00 |    6.67630769230769
 M17-4R.375        |   87.36 |       2 |  702.72 |    6.72026153846154
```

Comment: Are you aware of column operations? How would you go for just inserting the first column (amount at end of week one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```py
for i in range(13):
    if i==0:
        df[f'onhand_w{i+1}'] = df.loc[:,"onhand"] -  df.loc[:,'weekly']
    else:
        df[f'onhand_w{i+1}'] = df.loc[:,f'onhand_w{i}'] -  df.loc[:,'weekly']
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for the help!
For anyone that may use this in the future, you will want to make sure the two columns ('weekly' and 'onhand' in this example) are of the same data type.
I needed to run the following:

df['weekly'] = df['weekly'].astype(float)
df['onhand'] = df['onhand'].astype(float)